# How to properly parse HTML string with style and CSS and append it to the DOM

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, dom

Working on a javascript widget, I need to add some styled HTML to a page, without jQuery or `document.write`.

I have two javascript variables (from a JSON parsed file), `widgetCode` that contains HTML code and `widgetStyle` that contains CSS rules.

Here is the original HTML, before being modified by the javascript:

```
<h1 class="red">Title</h1>
<div class="target"></div>
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   var widgetCode = '<div class="red" style="text-decoration: underline;">My beautiful widget</div>',
    widgetStyle = '.red{color:red;}',
    parser = new DOMParser(),
    parsed = parser.parseFromString(widgetCode, "text/xml"),
    target = document.getElementsByClassName("target")[0],
    head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    style = document.createElement('style');

    // Append HTML element
    target.appendChild(parsed.documentElement);

    // Append CSS rules to HEAD
    style.type = 'text/css';
    if (style.styleSheet) style.styleSheet.cssText = widgetStyle;
    else style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(widgetStyle));
    head.appendChild(style);
});
```

Here are both on CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYavBP

The problem is, after the HTML and JavaScript were inserted, the widget content properly shows up in the page, but the class and style attributes seems to be ignored (although the `h1` original tag, that also has the `red` class, turns red as it should).

What am I missing here ? Why does the browser seem to ignore style ? Do I have to refresh it somehow ?

Edit: Actually, I just noticed that my code is working on Firefox and Safari. The problem seems to be Google Chrome (for Mac at least) specific.

Comment: WRT your edit: The text shows up in red, but not underlined in Mozilla!

Comment: It does work in both browsers when you write `target.innerHTML += widgetCode;` but I'm pretty sure that was not what you was asking about.

Comment: Well it doesn't answer my question but it certainly solves my problem, thanks. I don't know why I was sure I had to use DOMParser.